# Ajax rating tool in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ms-access-2007, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Hi I have a problem with my code, I am implementing a rating application. I have connected a access database to my website. I then added in the ajax control and gridview etc..
this is my code so far..

```
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>

  <asp:GridView ID="gvwMake" runat="server" DataKeyNames="MachineID"
   BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px"
   CellPadding="3" AllowPaging="True"                                           
   OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvwMake_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Make" HeaderText="Make" />
            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Image"></asp:ImageField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Machine Rating">
            <ItemTemplate>
                    <cc1:Rating ID="Rating1"
                    AutoPostBack="true" OnChanged="OnRatingChanged" runat="server"
                    StarCssClass="Star" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" 
                    EmptyStarCssClass="Star"
                    FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar" 
                    CurrentRating='<%# Eval("Rating") %>'>
               </cc1:Rating>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

That all seems to be working fine however the problem is with the code behind.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using AjaxControlToolkit;

public partial class rate : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataSet ds = MachineClass.getMachine();
        gvwMake.DataSource = ds.Tables["dtMachine"];
        gvwMake.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void gvwMake_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gvwMake.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    DataSet ds = MachineClass.getMachine();
    gvwMake.DataSource = ds.Tables["dtMachine"];
    gvwMake.DataBind();
}

protected void gvwMake_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string strID = gvwMake.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
    Session["TID"] = strID;
    Response.Redirect("~/Result.aspx");

}


protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = MachineClass.getMachine(txtSearch.Text);
    gvwMake.DataSource = ds.Tables["dtMachine"];

    gvwMake.DataBind();

}

private void ShowData()
{

    using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(
        "SELECT TOP 20 Products.ProductID, Products.ProductName," +
        " Products.UnitPrice, Products.SupplierID, " +
        "Products.CustomerRating FROM Products",
        new OleDbConnection(
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["comac.mdb.accdb"].ToString())))
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.SelectCommand.Connection.Open();
        da.Fill(dt);
        this.gvwMake.DataSource = dt;
        this.gvwMake.DataBind();
    }

}

protected void Rating1_Changed(object sender,
          AjaxControlToolkit.RatingEventArgs e)
{
    AjaxControlToolkit.Rating myRating =
              (AjaxControlToolkit.Rating)sender;
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rexLineNo =
      new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("ctl\\d+");

    this.updateRating(this.MachineId(
       rexLineNo.Match(myRating.UniqueID).ToString()), e.Value);

}

private string MachineId(string LineNo)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow r in this.gvwMake.Rows)
    {
        Label lblMachineId = (Label)r.FindControl("lblMachineId");

        if (lblMachineId.UniqueID.Contains(LineNo))
        {
            return lblMachineId.Text;
        }
    }

    return string.Empty;
}

private void updateRating(string MachineId, string Rating)
{

    OleDbParameter paramRating = new OleDbParameter("@Rating", Rating);
    OleDbParameter paramMachineId =
       new OleDbParameter("@MachineId", MachineId);


    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(
        "UPDATE Machines SET CustomerRating " +
        "= @Rating WHERE Machines.MachineID=@MachineId",
        new OleDbConnection(
         ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["comac.mdb.accdb"].ToString())))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramRating);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramMachineId);
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
}
```

}

This is my first time using the ajax rating control and not sure if the codes suitable for it when i run the webpage i get an error message 
'ASP.rate_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'OnRatingChanged' and no extension method 'OnRatingChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.rate_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I have fixed that error but any time i try and run it i am getting other errors, has anyone done this before and know if the code needs altered

Comment: What change did you make in the code to fix the issue and what is the other error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Okay here is the C# code. You will have to import the following namespaces:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using AjaxControlToolkit;

//the page_onload add the following code

 if (!IsPostBack)
 {
        gvFruits.DataSource = GetData("SELECT FruitId, FruitName, ISNULL((SELECT AVG(Rating) FROM Fruit_Ratings WHERE FruitId = Fruits.FruitId), 0) Rating FROM Fruits");
        gvFruits.DataBind();
 }

private static DataTable GetData(string query)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                sda.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
}

//and here is the code full functioning app for rating.[Full functioning rating app code][1]



  [1]: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-ASPNet-AJAX-Rating-Control-inside-GridView-TemplateField-ItemTemplate.aspx
```

Comment: I have added this code and still getting the same error Specified cast is not valid

Answer (score 1):

What I could see from the below part of your code:

```
<ItemTemplate>
                    <cc1:Rating ID="Rating1"
                    AutoPostBack="true" OnChanged="OnRatingChanged" runat="server"
                    StarCssClass="Star" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" 
                    EmptyStarCssClass="Star"
                    FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar" 
                    CurrentRating='<%# Eval("Rating") %>'>
               </cc1:Rating>
</ItemTemplate>
```

is the place where you use the Rating Control, you are **assigning  OnChanged Event to a Code behind method OnRatingChanged** (mentioned as `OnChanged="OnRatingChanged"`in your code) and since your **code behind does not have any method named OnRatingChanged** the error is thrown saying 'ASP.rate_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'OnRatingChanged'.

So if you are really not using this event then remove the event (remove the part: `OnChanged="OnRatingChanged"` from your code) or in case if you are using this then include an appropriate 'OnRatingChanged' method in your code behind.

Comment: Yeah it was named slightly different I have sorted that now I still kepp getting the error System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
<cc1:Rating ID="Rating" its referring to this line of code again. Its attached to a databse that has a rating feild in it so dont see what the problem could be

Comment: @user3432846: This error could be because of the diff datatype declaration in the DB side. CurrentRating property of the Ajax Rating control holds the Initial rating value. I doubt the initial rating value you are binding here is not an int, so please check if the Rating binding field in the DB has int value ( or it is of int type)

Comment: @user3432846: This error could be because of the diff datatype declaration in the DB side. CurrentRating property of the Ajax Rating control holds the Initial rating value. I doubt the initial rating value you are binding here is not an int, so please check if the Rating binding field in the DB has int value ( or it is of int type)

Comment: I changed it to an int however there is no data in this field in the db because its where i want me info to be stored.

Comment: This is my trace log

Specified cast is not valid. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Source Error:

Comment: Line 42:                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Machine Rating">
Line 43:                 <ItemTemplate>
Line 44:                         <cc1:Rating ID="Rating"
Line 45:                         AutoPostBack="true" OnChanged="OnRatingChanged" runat="server"
Line 46:                         StarCssClass="Star" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="Star"

Comment: [InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
   ASP.rate_aspx.__DataBinding__control25(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\IFMComac\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\RateMyMachine\rate.aspx:44
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +85
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +15
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +187
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +94
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +15
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +187

Comment: System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +94
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +15
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[] fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource) +167
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +3724
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +67

Comment: System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +14
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) +123
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +33
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +138
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +30
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4

Comment: rate.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\IFMComac\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\RateMyMachine\rate.aspx.cs:20
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to do here in both aspx and code behind ?

Comment: @user3432846: I Think I found out the issue. Can you try setting 'Rating' DB bounded field's default value as 0 (int) in the DB side so that initially when the 'CurrentRating prperty' of AJAX Rating Control is trying to bind to the Rating DB field it will not have NULL value so it will not throw Cast Exception.

Comment: so what error are you getting now. Just post the Error type and the line in where it is thrown that wil do

Comment: @user3432846: also can you try using Bind instead of Eval that is try using 'CurrentRating='<%# Bind("Rating") %>' instead of 'CurrentRating='<%# Eval("Rating") %>' since Eval is just a read method whereas Bind method allows both read and write.

Comment: I was having a problem with bind thats why i changed it to eval

Comment: @user3432846 : so what is the issue now? what error are you getting?

Comment: @user3432846: Can you try 'CurrentRating='<%# Convert.ToInt16(Eval("Rating")) %>' instead of  instead of 'CurrentRating='<%# Eval("Rating") %>'?

Comment: tried that getting this error now System.InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types. still referring to line 45 <cc1:Rating ID="Rating1"

Comment: Can you try this 'CurrentRating='<%# Eval("Rating").ToString() %>' instead of 'CurrentRating='<%# Eval("Rating") %>' ?

Comment: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'int'

Comment: @user3432846: try this 'CurrentRating='<%# Convert.ToInt16(Eval("Rating").ToString()) %>'.

Comment: no working on something else right now, going to do a bit more research into it then try again

Answer (score 0):

Okay Try the demo from this website probably you will find it usefull>
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-ASPNet-AJAX-Rating-Control-inside-GridView-TemplateField-ItemTemplate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

first add ajax toolkit from your ajax toolbox and then apply followin coding with css.

```js
<style type="text/css">
.Star
{
    background-image: url(Images/rsz_star-deselect.png);
    height: 17px;
    width: 17px;
}
.WaitingStar
{
    /*background-image: url(images/WaitingStar.gif);*/
    height: 17px;
    width: 17px;
}
.FilledStar
{
    background-image: url(Images/rsz_star-select.png);
    height: 17px;
    width: 17px;
}
</style>
```

```js
<ItemTemplate>
                <cc1:Rating ID="Rating1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"
                    StarCssClass="Star" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="Star"
                    FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar" CurrentRating='<%# Eval("Rating") %>'>
                </cc1:Rating>
 </ItemTemplate>
```